# when deleting records, index seeding still high

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Ok, I am a bit less experienced in database topics, but consider the situation where you have a field named `id` in your table, and it's Indexable/Increment-seeding.

So maybe you have rows 1-60 , so id is between 1-60, and the increment is at "61".

Well if you delete rows 30-50, shouldn't the increment go back down to "31"? Filling in those 30-50 ids, and then going back to 61?

My Question::: Why doesn't MSSQL / SQL Server, do this? The missing unused ids between 30-50, are never to be used again.

Further, what if you manually inserted some rows, between id 500-600? When the increment gets to "500", will it not give a "duplicate key" error? ???

So if you have some sort of table that is constantly changed by every user---deleting, inserting, deleting, inserting, you better hope `id` is bigint, because it's going to quickly go into the 1,000,000+ area if you have enough users.

Comment: Note that a regular int provides over 2 billion positive values. bigint is a good choice if you expect int to still be limiting, though. You'd be hard pressed to overflow such a data type.

Comment: I agree. The nature of websites however is we never know when they turn out to be popular, so I go with bigint to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using autoincrement fields, it is highly recommended to just let SQL Server handle the values for you.  It does so in such a way as to minimize integrity conflicts.

That said, if you really want to reset the id values after a large delete, consider using `TRUNCATE TABLE` (which will reset the autoincrement value automatically) if you are purging the entire table, or [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) if you need finer control over how this works.

EDIT:

This is to demonstrate the behavior of SQL Server when there is a manually-perpetrated gap in autoincrement ID values:

```
BEGIN TRAN

create table #t1 (id int identity, data int)

insert into #t1 (data) values (1)
insert into #t1 (data) values (2)
insert into #t1 (data) values (3)
insert into #t1 (data) values (4)

select * from #t1

dbcc checkident(#t1, reseed, 10)

insert into #t1 (data) values (5)
insert into #t1 (data) values (6)
insert into #t1 (data) values (7)
insert into #t1 (data) values (8)

select * from #t1

dbcc checkident(#t1, reseed, 5)

insert into #t1 (data) values (9)
insert into #t1 (data) values (10)
insert into #t1 (data) values (11)
insert into #t1 (data) values (12)
insert into #t1 (data) values (13)
insert into #t1 (data) values (14)
insert into #t1 (data) values (15)
insert into #t1 (data) values (16)

select * from #t1 -- this will demonstrate that SQL Server is quite happy to duplicate IDs if you have manually introduced a gap and then reset the ID to a lower value...

truncate table #t1

insert into #t1 (data) values (1)
insert into #t1 (data) values (2)
insert into #t1 (data) values (3)
insert into #t1 (data) values (4)

select * from #t1 -- this will show that TRUNCATE TABLE does (yes, really!) reset the autoincrement id value.

create table #t2 (id int identity primary key, data int)

insert into #t2 (data) values (1)
insert into #t2 (data) values (2)
insert into #t2 (data) values (3)
insert into #t2 (data) values (4)

select * from #t2

dbcc checkident(#t2, reseed, 10)

insert into #t2 (data) values (5)
insert into #t2 (data) values (6)
insert into #t2 (data) values (7)
insert into #t2 (data) values (8)

select * from #t2

dbcc checkident(#t2, reseed, 5)

-- the errors you are about to get should demonstrate that if there is an integrity constraint (in this case, the ever-popular PRIMARY KEY constraint) you will get errors when attempting to insert duplicates.

insert into #t2 (data) values (9)
insert into #t2 (data) values (10)
insert into #t2 (data) values (11)
insert into #t2 (data) values (12)
insert into #t2 (data) values (13)
insert into #t2 (data) values (14)
insert into #t2 (data) values (15)
insert into #t2 (data) values (16)

select * from #t2

ROLLBACK
```

Comment: This doesn't really help you if your key is used as a FK to other tables, in which case you have a more complex set of scripts to write.

Comment: @Joe: Of course!  Integrity issues are always of first priority.

Comment: So what happens if I did insert a number of records manually while there is an auto-increment id? What happens when the number gets to that id?

Comment: @mwigdahl I just wonder - does Truncate table resets autoinc counter, really? I dont think so...

Comment: @Dexter: It simply attempts to insert a duplicate of that ID.  If there's no integrity constraint, it will succeed.  If there is an integrity constraint, it will fail.  In neither case is it likely to be desirable, which is why you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @mwigdahl Yep, checked truncate table, you are completely right, thanks!

Comment: @mwigdahl, from my understanding, in MySQL, the auto_increment feature skips over these used IDs, at say 500-600, it would come to 500, then skip to 601. Isn't this how it works in MSSQL too? Or does MSSQL desire to be annoying and give out a duplicate-key-error to the user instead of correcting itself.

Comment: @Dexter:  Wow, apparently no one believes anything I say today!  SQL Server is not MySQL.  I've edited my answer to include a test script to demonstrate that what I originally said is correct.

Comment: @mwigdahl: I don't know what you originally said as it relates to my question. From your answer, I gather that the designers of MSSQL are dumb and generate errors if a database admin decides to manually insert values, and the designers of MySQL were smart and have programmed their increment to skip duplicates.

Comment: @Dexter: I was mostly referring to Oleg's comment.  As far as your conclusions, that's certainly a possible interpretation!  Without knowing how costly the dupe-avoiding code is it's hard to say whether that's a good decision overall.  Certainly MSSQL's philosophy is that if you are going to take manual control of something that was set up to be automatic, you are responsible for properly dealing with possible issues arising from that usage.  It is very interesting that MySQL supports this case, though!

Comment: @mwigdahl thank you for your very objective and intelligent opinion on the matter. I will investigate further.

Answer (score 4):

If that field is used as the unique id, you should not want it to reuse a value. Once deleted, a value should not be reused.

If the field is being auto generated, you should not be manually setting values in it, except in special cases (like replication).

And yes; you need to make sure you choose a large enough data type. Don't pull a Y2K-like stunt and restrict your app unnecessarily.

Comment: Ok so what if I did insert a manual amount of rows (500-600) ? How would you rectify the situation. Yes I always use bigint for id (I might have forgotten to make some of them unsigned).  Why shouldn't a value be re-used btw?

Comment: @Dexter: What about audit or history rows in another table

Comment: The autoincrement field should handle that situation once you reenable it. IDs should not be reused because it would cause confusion. Imagine if you delete a post and its id is reused - links to the old post now magically - and confusingly - point to an unrelated item. This goes beyond confusing a user who bookmarked something; it would likely create real bugs in your app.

Comment: You are right about that. So Are you saying that if I have manually inserted 500-600, then when autoincrement comes to 499 then 500, will it not give error and it will skip over to 601? That's the results I've seen in MySQL, is that emulated in MSSQL ?

Comment: I was actually under the impression such an insert would immediately set the 'seed' to 601, regardless of the now 'blank' area, but I admit I'm not sure. This would be trivial to test in ssms with a test database, though.